# Weblogic 12.1.1 and 12.1.2

Tags: jakarta-ee, weblogic

I've upgraded weblogic from 12.1.1 to 12.1.2 and application started failing during the startup. It tells

> weblogic.utils.compiler.ToolFailureException: Neither `<prefer-application-packages>` nor`<prefer-application-resources>` can be specified when `<prefer-web-inf-classes>` is turned on in weblogic.xml

Here's my weblogic.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app">
  <container-descriptor>
        <prefer-web-inf-classes>false</prefer-web-inf-classes>
        <servlet-reload-check-secs>-1</servlet-reload-check-secs>
    </container-descriptor>
    <session-descriptor>
        <http-proxy-caching-of-cookies>true</http-proxy-caching-of-cookies>
    </session-descriptor>
    <jsp-descriptor>
        <page-check-seconds>-1</page-check-seconds>
        <working-dir>./work</working-dir>
        <backward-compatible>true</backward-compatible>
    </jsp-descriptor>
    <library-ref>
        <library-name>jstl</library-name>
        <specification-version>1.1</specification-version>
        <implementation-version>1.1.2</implementation-version>
        <exact-match>true</exact-match>
    </library-ref>
</weblogic-web-app>
```

Why it's not workig?

Comment: The default value for `prefer-web-inf-classes` is false anyway so see what happens when you removed that line from your `weblogic.xml` file

Comment: it works, when I do that. It works with false as well. But with true - it fails with the excption I wrote(

Comment: @Nick, did you open a Service Request? This looks like to be a bug and may be already fixed. Opening an SR will surely help you figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

It looks WAD: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e21049/weblogic_xml.htm#WBAPP659

It cannot be both deployment descriptor set the "same" configuration (it is redundant).

Comment: What does WAD means ?

Comment: WAD = Works As Designed :)

Comment: He has correctly used only one descriptor! please have a look at his `weblogix.xml`.